# I'm trying to detect whether a div contains an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, if-statement

I am currently doing the following but it isn't working for me (i.e. is still called even when there IS an iFrame inside the div):

```
if($('#bodytext-' + postID + ':has(iframe)').length > -1) {

    $(this).parent().append(ytCode);

}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Note that there is no special scope in a condition, so `this` would have to come from somewhere else !

Comment: Just to be clear -- you want the append to only happen when there is NOT an iframe already there?

Comment: @JacobM - yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2):

If there's no iFrame in the div, the length of the resulting jQuery object will be 0, which is greater than -1. If there is an iFrame, the length will be 1, which is also greater than -1.

Comment: Even if I put '.length === 0' in there, it still appends the code.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do, but if you only want the append to happen when there is NO iframe present, than presumably you want `length>0` in your `if` condition.

Comment: You pasted your javascript.  We want to see the HTML. Also, in the javascript you posted, it's not clear where `postID` is coming from.

Comment: @JamesAnderson585 Your element doesn't contain a iframe, because you havent added it yet. Maybe you want to check `length === 0`

Comment: @JacobM - I think the problem actually lies with the 'each' bit in the code I sent you (http://pastie.org/private/g8tft193ctaayfj11ydfg). It is going through every single $('post-text a') when I only want it to go through the last one on the page...

Answer (score 0):

Is it it still call even there is not any iframe inside the div?

Because the length property return value always greater than -1. The minimum is 0 it mean there is not any item.

Your code should be

```
if($('#bodytext-' + postID + ':has(iframe)').length > 0) {

    $(this).parent().append(ytCode);

}
```

Comment: It isn't called at all if I put this :-(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Here's what I did:

```
    if($(this).closest('p').find("iframe").length === 0) {

        $(this).closest('p').append(ytCode);

    }
```